# Paper size changes for unknown reasons

Tags: paper-size

I have a document that's supposed to compile in `a4paper`. Until recently, that worked just fine, however now it's using the same width, but a significantly increased height. It's pretty much a 2:1 ratio now.

I narrowed it down to the following code:

```
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\renewcommand{\rmfamily}{%
\fontfamily{ptm}%
\fontsize{12}{1.5pt}%
}
```

When I replace this with just `usepackage{geometry}`, everything is back to normal.

The preamble also contains these potentially relevant clauses:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % part of standard header for European documents
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % part of standard header for European documents
\usepackage[babel,english=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-10-15]
```

(It also contains some formatting tricks, none of them changes the paper size or any existing command or length, though. Plus, I doubt it's because of StackEngine or BibLaTeX.)

I'm not sure if it's specific to the toolkit I use (PDFLaTeX with TeXLive backend and TeXlipse frontend under Windows 10) because I didn't really try it in a different environment.

What about this code would change the paper size and what should I do instead?

Comment: I'm not sure what "TeXMaker backend and TeXlipse frontend" means, Texmaker is an editor and TeXlipse is a (plugin for an) editor, so both are arguably frontend. So which of the two do you use? And more importantly, which LaTeX distribution do you use (TeX Live, MiKTeX, MacTeX) and on which operating system (Windows/Mac/Linux/other)? Also, although the `geometry` package has (obviously) a big influence on the geometry of the document, other parts of the code also play a role, such as the documentclass. Could you provide a small but _complete_ document that shows this issue?

Comment: @Marijn Whoops, I meant TeX Live ^-^'

Comment: Thanks for the extra code - it is however still not a complete, reproducible document (i.e., no `\begin{document}` and contents and `\end{document}`), also it is not minimal (most of the packages you mention do not influence the behavior). So it would help to answer the question if you make a document that can be compiled, is as small as possible (no irrelevant packages) and that shows the problem when it is compiled. Verify yourself, before posting, if your example indeed shows the issue when it is copied to an empty document and compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out I was hallucinating the wrong paper size. What made me think it had changed was the decrease in page amount which was caused by the fact that the margin was decreased properly, but the code that was meant to increase the font size and line spacing was doing nothing. In other words, this:

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\renewcommand{\rmfamily}{%
\fontfamily{ptm}%
\fontsize{12}{1.5pt}%
}
```

doesn't work for changing font, font size and line spacing. The code that actually works is, in fact, much simpler: Add `12pt` to the optional parameters of `\documentclass` and apply

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
```